# Can shared object have its own thread running in the background?

Tags: linux, multithreading, shared-libraries

I am a beginner of Linux programming and I am not sure if what I expect is feasible.  I would appreciate if someone could give me some tips.

What I want to do is to develop a shared object (.so file), which could be used by multiple applications.  If one of those applications calls an initialize function in the shared object, a new thread will be created to run an infinite loop to accept incoming events.  This thread will keep running even after the initialize function return.  Thus all applications could keep sending events to this thread for processing.

I wonder if this could be achieved?  Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Threads live in the context of a process and die when the process dies. Two processes cannot share a thread. Placing code in a shared object doesn't magically make it possible. You possibly want to create an entirely new process, not a thread (and use a regular executable program rather than a shared object in order to run it). Or maybe not, it's hard to tell. Perhaps you should describe your project in more detail.

Comment: Thanks n.m., your thought enlightens me.  What I want to make is something like a data processing server running in the background, and multiple applications could send request to that server for data processing.  Although this could be done by implementing a real server, I think that's quite heavy weight and the performance may not be good enough for realtime data processing.  I wonder if there is a way to do it with better performance, instead of sending the request via network, I prefer to send it via a function call.  Is it possible?

Comment: No, you cannot call a function in another process (or thread).

Comment: What makes you think using a real server will have poor performance? Have you tested it and found it to be lacking? You're trying to make a decision without real information. Unix-domain sockets and pipes are quite efficient. Failing that (but only after having tried it) you could try to go with shared memory, which would help if there is _a lot_ of data to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in the comments, this cannot be done: you cannot directly invoke a function in another process. This is why RPC, IPC, web services etc. were invented.

Comment: RPC was invented to call methods _on other hosts_. Web services were invented to have a data-driven contract to other hosts, which should not depend on the implementation (methods).